# How to get the highest page number using xpath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I've written an xpath expression to get the highest value of `page number` from some `html elements`. However, with the below xpath I'm getting the last text which is `Next Page` in this case. I wish my xpath act in such a way so that I can get the highest number, as in `6` using it.

The elements upon which the xpath should be applied:

```
content = """
<div class="nav-links"><span aria-current="page" class="page-numbers current"><span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">Page </span>1</span>
<a class="page-numbers" href="https://page/2/"><span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">Page </span>2</a>
<span class="page-numbers dots">…</span>
<a class="page-numbers" href="https://page/6/"><span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">Page </span>6</a>
<a class="next page-numbers" href="https://page/2/"><span class="screen-reader-text">Next Page</span></a></div>
"""
```

What I've tried so far:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

root = fromstring(above_content)
pagenum = root.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'page-numbers')][last()]/span")[0].text
print(pagenum)
```

Output I'm having:

```
Next Page
```

Output I wish to have:

```
6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use exact class name to avoid fetching Next link:

```
//a[@class="page-numbers"][last()]
```

Note that `contains(@class,'page-numbers')` will return you links with numbers and Next while `@class="page-numbers"` numbers only

Comment: Your solution never fails @sir Andersson. Yes, it did it. Thanks a lot.